# Centos 7 xrdp allow connection from specific IP's only

Tags: centos, remote-desktop, xrdp

I have installed `xrdp` on a local Centos 7 Server using command:

```
yum install xrdp
```

I have turned off the firewall and i need to keep it turned off. Its working fine and I can connect to the server using native/built-in windows remote desktop client. Is it possible to configure `xrdp` on the server so that it allows remote desktop connection **only for specific IP's**? The scenario is, multiple people have ssh access to the server, but I need to give only specific people remote desktop access.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "turned off the firewall", but what if you just create firewall rules for `xrdp` while allowing everything else? That seems to be exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: It also possible that anyone with `ssh` access will be able to get RDP access via ssh forwarding, regardless of ip-address based restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on why the firewall *needs* to be turned off, and what you are really trying to achive by blocking some users from using xrdp?

If it is enough for you that a user cannot simply access xrdp the normal way then the Security section of the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/sesman.ini.5.html), specifically `TerminalServerUsers` can do this.

But as larsks noted, as long as users have normal ssh access, they can get into an x-Session one way or another. (either through port forwarding, or ssh x forwarding)
Regardless of this (if xrdp connects only to local sessions), they could do everything they can do on the GUI on the shell anyway.